# TabPage is bigger than TabControl

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

So I have a problem with the TabControl in visual studio 2015. 
I have 2 tabs that are scrollable but the right scroll bar disappears because the tab page goes out of bounds and is bigger than the actual tab controller. Here is an image reference: [Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzdqL.png)

The tab control was created at design time, by simply dragging and dropping it on the form. It is anchored to top and left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TreeView is bigger and resizes the Tab. You should ensure that the control keeps the correct size using Dock.Fill or Anchor Left | Right | Top | Bottom.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks a lot, did not even think about that !

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoScroll` property to `true` for that specific tabpage.

Say, for tabpage1:

```
tabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
```

You can also perform the same during design time by clicking on the tabpage and setting the `AutoScroll` to `true` from the Properties window.

Don't just set the anchors to only `Top` and `Left`, but anchor on all four sides:

```
AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom
```